# Make all the uitextfields empty in viewWillAppear / viewWillDisappear

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield

I have 8-10 UITextFields like a form. I need to clear all of them either in viewWillAppear or viewWillDisappear, because the textfields should be empty when I land on the view for the second time. Now, 1. Which method of the above two should I use for that purpose , and more important, 2. Is there any way to clear all the textfields at a single shot ?
        I know, one way is simply to take each fields and make textfield.text = @"", but is there any better way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (UIView *subview in [yourView subviews])
    if([subview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
         [(UITextField*)subview setText:@""];
```

Answer (score 0):

Clear them all at once!

```
for (UIView* view in self.view.subviews){
    if (view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class])
        view.text = @"";
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
for(id view in [self.view subviews]){
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
         view.text = @"";
    }
}
```

Search through all the subviews on your view (above I set `self.view`) and reset them if its a `UITextField`.

Comment: Both SurfDev and pro_metedor:Thanks for your try, but as Ravi has answered, you need to typecast view as (UITextField *), otherwise it throws error as 'property 'text' not found on object of type 'id''. If you do not typecast, then declare it as UITextView instead of UIView or id inside the for loop.
@Ravi: Thanks man .. It worked.